# show numbers of orders on home page in magento2

Tags: magento2

in the home page show, the number of orders that are placed and when the user placed the order that number should increase in home page 
for eg the current order placed are 500 and when user place the order it should 501 shown in home page in magento2

Comment: You want to display the order count of the logged in user or overall order count you want to display in home page?

Comment: overall order count

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Create a helper and add the below code to it,

Helper path be like

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
}
public function getCollection()
{
    $total = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection();
    return $total->getSize();
}
```

}

then in your phtml you can call like below

```
echo $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getCollection();
```

you can call any of the phtml in the home page to get this information.

To call a phtml only on home page follow the below steps

create a cms_index_index.xml in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

then add the below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="sales_total" template="Vendor_Module::total.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**Vendor_Module** - this should you namespace_modulename

And also place total.phtml in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/total.phtml

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok i will check this